# Re-execution of node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, mean-stack

I'm trying to executes the following code in node.js:-

```
var i = 3
var p = Promise.resolve(i)
while (i > 0) {
  (i => {
    p = p.then(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {        

            let query1=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                db.query(
                    "select * from users limit 1;",function(err,order){
                        if(err){
                            reject(err)
                        }
                        if(order){
                            if(order.length==0){
                                reject('No order found')
                            }else{
                                resolve(order)

                            }
                        }
                })    
            })

            query1.then(function(userdata){

                if (userdata) {
                    console.log("query 1 start");
                    let query2=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                        db.query(
                            "select * from users limit 1;",function(err,order){
                                if(err){
                                    reject(err)
                                }
                                if(order){
                                    if(order.length==0){
                                        reject('No order found')
                                    }else{
                                        resolve(order)

                                    }
                                }
                        })    
                    })
                    query2.then(function(userdata){

                        if (userdata) {
                            console.log("query 2 start");
                            i--;
                            return true;                            
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("error");                            
                        }
                    })
                    return true;                    
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error");                    
                }
            })        
      })
    })
  })(i)
//   i--
}

p = p.then(data => console.log('execution ends'))
```

when it executes, it prints the following :-

```
query 1 start
query 2 start
```

And when query2 executes it stucked between while loop. but, I want to execute this code 3 time using while loop and my expected output will look like this :-

```
query 1 start
query 2 start
query 1 start
query 2 start
query 1 start
query 2 start
execution ends
```

So anyone have idea how can I again start code execution after query2 successful executes?

Comment: //   i-- why i-- is commented?

Comment: @Nishant Dixit because, I want i-- only after query2 successful executes.